# 'WithOAthBearerToken' is not a member of string

Tags: vb.net, async-await, flurl

I'm using Flurl to connect to an API site, I need to do a Post and Put to create a new record and update, I have two different functions for each operation, this is one

```
 Public Async Function CreateIdentityAsync(ByVal tok As String, ByVal accountId As String, ByVal model As IdentityModel) As Task(Of IdentityModel) Implements IIDentityService.CreateIdentityAsync
        Return Await (_serviceUrl.WithOAuthBearerToken(tok).AppendPathSegment($"api/v1/accounts/{accountId}/identities").AllowAnyHttpStatus().PostJsonAsync(model)).As(Of IdentityModel)()
        'Return Nothing
 End Function
```

If I use `Import Flurl` I get this error:

> 'WithOAthBearerToken' is not a member of string

and if I use `Import Flurl.Http` I had this error:

> 'As'is not a member of 'Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)'.

Any idea of how can I fix it, and why is this happening?

Comment: You definitely need the `Import Flurl.Http` part. I don't know VB well enough to help with the other error, but it seems clear that the `.As(...)` method just doesn't exist.  I think you want the end of that line to look something like this: `.PostJsonAsync(Of IdentityModel)(model)`, though I'm not certain.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but no luck. I appreciate your help